# Notice: unserialize(): Error at offset XX (removing Paragraphs)

Tags: 8, database, paragraphs

I'm trying to remove Paragraphs and modules related to it manually (because I can't remove it completly from admin page).

I'm using UTF8 without BOM in Notepad++ when editing key_value BLOB file that I get form PhpMyAdmin and I see that error in my site:

```
Notice: unserialize(): Error at offset 76 of 42499 bytes in Drupal\Component\Serialization\PhpSerialize::decode() (line 21 of core\lib\Drupal\Component\Serialization\PhpSerialize.php).
```

My DB is in utf8mb4_general_ci. The change that I made into key_value table is removed a orphaned field and subtracted a value from the initial counter (a:37 to a:36 from that BLOB data).

I saw some php code related to serialize/unserialize but I think this problem could be solved from PhpMyAdmin without modifying core files. Looking for some hint.

Comment: I don’t understand the premise of the question. You can’t uninstall modules from the admin? Did you try using Drush as well? Editing the database manually is not advised as one error can result in this sort of situation.

Comment: I need to remove a field manually. I see that some data holds in key_value table from my DB.

If I change this info manually, I see serialized error. I thought that could be related to format coding (UTF8) but when I edit, I use the same that I modified in other fields as I commented before.

Maybe there is a way to delete this field from PhpMyAdmin without modifying the BLOB data manually and importing it again.

Comment: I still having this issue. I don't know if there is a way to analize the serialized data from BLOB files in order to fix this error.

Maybe someone can help. If I can't solve this thing in next days, I'll need to migrate the content to another instance of Drupal =/